# Auto-Redirecting after BigVideo.js video ends

Tags: video.js

I'm having trouble auto-redirecting after my video has ended using BigVideo.js. Not sure what's wrong here. Not only does this not redirect it completely breaks the player and the video does not play.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
  var BV;
  $(function() {
    // initialize BigVideo
    BV = new $.BigVideo();
    BV.init();
    BV.show('vids/video.mp4');
     BV.getPlayer().on("ended", function() {
window.location = "http://www.google.com";
    })
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code locally and the redirection worked without any problems.
I guess it depends on the browser type/version or other environment factor.

Try to properly unload the video element by:

```
BV.getPlayer().on("ended", function () {
    this.pause();
    delete(this);
    window.location = "http://www.google.com";
});
```

reference:
[How to properly unload/destroy a VIDEO element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258587/how-to-properly-unload-destroy-a-video-element)

hope that will do the trick :)