# Destroying the HTML video player?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to play a video over an embedded game of mine and when the video ends, I want it to disappear so that we seamlessly go from the intro to the game itself (can't insert the video into the game in the engine I'm working in). How can I do this? Currently, I have something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class = "container"><span>
<iframe src='...' />
<video autoplay> <source src="intro.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
</span></div>

<script>
    var video = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];

    video.onended = function(e) {
      # Don't know what to put in here
    };
</script>

</body></html>
```

Comment: Well, you can either hide the video or delete the entire element containing it. Do you need to re-use it later?

Comment: @briosheje - nope, I don't need it anymore after it plays out once

Comment: Just a thought but could you start with the game hidden and time the video.  Then, once the video is supposed to end, hide it and show the game.

Comment: @LoganHasbrouck - that suits me as well if not destroying the video doesn't impact performance but how do I hide and unhide them?

Comment: @Straightfw - Use javascript to show and hide their containing divs.

Comment: you cant use `.destroy();` on video tag

Comment: Here... this might be better instead of hiding the video after - this should remove it (link) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258587/how-to-properly-unload-destroy-a-video-element

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do it is by giving the exact same size to the game's element and the video.

Then you could hide the game with the inline css `display: none;` when the page starts, and once the video ends you can hide the video and display the game.

```
var game = document.getElementById("...");
var video = document.getElementById("...");

game.style.display = "none";

video.onended = function(e) {
  video.style.display = "none";
  // or if you want to destroy it permanently
  // video.parentNode.removeChild(video);
  // video = null;
  game.style.display = "";
};
```