# Video, memory management problems in Internet Explorer and Edge from many videos on page causing them to display dark/black and/or not play

Tags: javascript, html, dom, memory-management, html5-video

We have a page that contains 77 or so video thumbnails. When a video thumbnail is hovered over, video starts playing within the thumbnail space.

A problem occurs after many (8 to 60 depending on the system/browser) of them get hovered over. The video starts playing incorrectly, or not playing. Basically the flat/redundant areas turn all dark. In Edge, this corrects itself after a second or two, but for our client this is very undesirable behavior.

We made an improvement by pausing each video on mouse out by calling `pause()`, removing the `src` attribute, and then calling `load()` on the element with an empty `src` attribute, like so:

```
 function pauseVideo(e) {
     $('video', this).get(0).pause();
     $('video', this).get(0).removeAttribute('src');
     $('video', this).get(0).load();
 }
```

This clears up some memory, but the issue still occurs, though more of the videos can play before the problem becomes apparent.

I does appear to have something to do with memory, and exposes what appears to us to be a memory leak within the Microsoft browsers. Each video increases memory usage, and the memory never gets cleared, as it seems to in Chrome and Firefox. The problem usually occurs when memory usage approaches somewhere between 600mb to 1gb (depending on system) in the task manager. (Chrome always sits around ~500-550 megabytes.
Firefox sits around ~700-800 megabytes.)

We noticed some variance on when the behavior starts to occur that depends on video cards, but the issue always become present at some point.

All of these videos are showed in multiple places on the page. So one thing I was wondering was if it is possible to share video memory between elements.

There are a couple other issues that may be related. In IE the videos go completely black, and their dimensions change onscreen which can change the page layout.

Here is a **related** issue, but it is **not a duplicate**, as it doesn't not provide a question or solution about having to facilitate 80 or so videos on one page: [How to properly unload/destroy a VIDEO element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258587/how-to-properly-unload-destroy-a-video-element)

We're testing on IE version 11.228.17134.0 and Edge version 42.17134.1.0, both currently the latest.

The desired functionality originally was for the videos to pause on the frame when the user moused off the video, but right now appears we wont be able to do that if we have to unload the video.

I will be adding more information about this issue throughout the day as it becomes available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Our team has a script that detects if DOM elements are within the viewable area on the page, e.i. not scrolled above the top or below the bottom. As the user scrolls, the script adds/removes a class, and dispatches custom events for each element that has the behavior added. I was able to leverage this system to pause, remove, and dispose (garbage collect) video elements that are not in view, and then, repopulate them as they come back into view, with the original properties stored in an array of objects associated with each video/thumbnail.

This disposes the video. The function must be called with `.call()`, like: `disposeVideo.call(videoElement)`;

```
var disposeVideo = function () {
  this.pause();
  delete(this);
  $(this).remove();
}
```

*It's odd that though `delete(this)` is a hack, and shouldn't work in any browser, it appears to work in all browsers, according to comments I've read around this issue, and my findings in IE/Edge.*

On IE (not Edge) this has a side effect of slowing down page scrolling. This is caused by the our in-view checking applied to 80 items on the page, or if it is to do with re-downloading posters (thumbnail images) and video, because it does appear to not be effectively caching these assets to be immediately (re)available to the renderer.

Another side effect (also in IE) related to the above, is that as you scroll the videos appear blank until assets are re-downloaded. We're opting to use images layered behind the videos in favor of using the poster attribute for the videos elements that get removed. This way there will never be blank video thumbnails onscreen.

**Update:** It is possible that having two or more video elements onscreen can cause the problem. We resorted to only showing one (which worked 100%) but did not try to determine a likely maximum number of video elements.