# How to Reset VIDEO & SOURCE DOM Memory Groups in a React Web Application (Firefox)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, dom, memory, browser

I'm working on a real-time media player React application that alternates displaying fullscreen  &  elements in the browser (Firefox in particular).

My concern is specifically with memory. The application never reloads in the window and I see the memory profile jumping in size after every play of the video to be streamed with each subsequent load, and never dropping back down to the baseline.

You can observe both the SOURCE & VIDEO memory groups by opening the developer tools (f12) and opening the 'memory' tab, taking a snapshot and switching to the aggregate view.

I have tried following the solutions in this [stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258587/how-to-properly-unload-destroy-a-video-element) but to no avail.

I have a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-mnrrpx?file=/src/MediaPlayer.tsx:0-665) example and [live](https://mnrrpx.csb.app/) example.

But the main two components to understand is the `MediaPlayer` and the `VideoPlayer`

Media Player:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./MediaStyles.css";
import ImagePlayer from "./ImagePlayer";
import VideoPlayer from "./VideoPlayer";

const MediaPlayer = () => {
  const [mediaSwap, setMediaSwap] = useState<boolean>(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setMediaSwap((swap: boolean) => !swap);
    }, 5000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [mediaSwap]);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="fullscreen-container">
        <div className="media-container">
          {mediaSwap ? <VideoPlayer /> : <ImagePlayer />}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default MediaPlayer;
```

VideoPlayer:

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

const VideoPlayer = () => {
  const videoRef = useRef<HTMLVideoElement | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (videoRef.current) {
      console.log("current mounted removal");
      videoRef.current.pause();
      videoRef.current.removeAttribute("src");
      videoRef.current.load();
    }

    return () => {
      if (videoRef.current) {
        console.log("current unmounted removal");
        videoRef.current.pause();
        videoRef.current.removeAttribute("src");
        videoRef.current.load();
      }
    };
  }, [videoRef.current]);

  return (
    <div>
      <video id="spotlight video" ref={videoRef} autoPlay muted playsInline>
        <source src="https://ibcdigitalsignageblob.blob.core.windows.net/fe3c4826-4e72-4cd4-a938-382d67a8badf/assets/2023-09-19_02_10_55_4kvid.mp4" />
      </video>
    </div>
  );
};

export default VideoPlayer;
```

Answer (score 0):

The ref value `videoRef.current` will likely have changed by the time the useEffect cleanup function runs. Copy `videoRef.current` to a variable inside the useEffect, and use that variable in the cleanup function.

`src/VideoPlayer.tsx`

```
const VideoPlayer = () => {
  const videoRef = useRef<HTMLVideoElement | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const videoRefCurrent = videoRef.current; // <--- Here

    if (videoRefCurrent) {
      console.log("current mounted removal");
      videoRefCurrent.pause();
      videoRefCurrent.removeAttribute("src");
      videoRefCurrent.load();
    }

    return () => {
      if (videoRefCurrent) {
        console.log("current unmounted removal");
        videoRefCurrent.pause();
        videoRefCurrent.removeAttribute("src");
        videoRefCurrent.load();
      }
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <video id="spotlight video" ref={videoRef} autoPlay muted playsInline>
        <source src="https://ibcdigitalsignageblob.blob.core.windows.net/fe3c4826-4e72-4cd4-a938-382d67a8badf/assets/2023-09-19_02_10_55_4kvid.mp4" />
      </video>
    </div>
  );
};
```